# Fastest algorithm to take the product of all subsets

Tags: arithmetic, fewest-operations

Given `n` numbers in an array (you can't assume they are integers), I would like to compute the product of all subsets of size `n-1`.

You can do this by  multiplying all the numbers together and then dividing by each one in turn, as long as none of the numbers is zero.  However, how quickly can you do this with no division?

> If you don't allow division, what is the minimum number of
>   arithmetic operations (e.g. multiplication and addition) needed to compute the product of all subsets of size
>   n-1?

Clearly you can do it in `(n-1)*n` multiplications.

To clarify, the output is `n` different products and the only operations apart from reading and writing to memory allowed are multiplication, addition and subtraction.

**Example**

If the input has three numbers `2,3,5`, then the output is three numbers `15 = 3*5`, `10 = 2*5` and `6 = 2*3`.

**Winning criterion**

Answers should give an exact formula for the number of arithmetic operations their code will use in terms of `n`.  To make life simple, I will just plug `n = 1000` into your formula to judge its score. The lower the better.

If it's too hard to produce an exact formula for your code, you can just run it for `n = 1000` and count the arithmetic operations in  the code.  An exact formula would be best however.

You should add your score for `n=1000` to your answer for easy comparison.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first question!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thank you!

Comment: Do the products have to be listed in any particular order?

Comment: @xnor No. Any order will do.

Comment: May we count multiplying by 1 as free? Otherwise I'd define a custom-multiplication function that does this.

Comment: For simplicity, all multiplications should be counted in the score, even by 1.

Comment: Would it be against the rules to do a whole bunch of multiplications in parallel by concatenating numbers together with sufficiently many spacer 0 digits?

Comment: @xnor Yes it would!

Comment: Are operations like `>=` or `max` also banned? You might want to make this an [atomic code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) so people don't try to use language features to get around your restrictions.

Comment: @xnor I basically don't want to allow any operations that are going to substitute for the arithmetic operations via some trickery.  I really want to know how you can do it using a small number of multiplications, subtractions and additions.

Comment: Do the operations such as `+` on _indices_ count? If this is the case, does array indexing count as well? (since it is after all syntactic sugar for addition and dereferencing).

Comment: I removed the restricted-code tag since my understanding is that atomic-code-golf supersedes it.

Comment: @nore You can look up/access/read the input elements for free.  All the arithmetic operations in your code should be counted however.

Comment: @Arthur does this mean a loop has a cost of the number of operations for the counter?

Comment: Are architecture-specific tricks allowed in our answers?

Comment: @nore OK I give in :)   Just count arithmetic operations that involve the input in some way.

Comment: _Clearly you can do it in `(n-1)*n` multiplications_ You mean `(n-2)*n`, right?

Comment: Does a SIMD operation count as a single operation?

Comment: @Veedrac Not for this challenge, sorry.

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick, but what does it mean to multiply two or more sets?  No definition of *set* that I know has a *multiply* operation.  Perhaps you could give a worked example for what the result would be for a small input array?

Comment: @TobySpeight If the input has three number `1,2,3`, then  the output is three numbers `6 = 2*3,3 = 1*3` and `2 = 1*2`. Does that help?

Comment: Oh, so you're asking for a *set* of outputs - no wonder I was confused.  The way it's worded in the question suggests you are looking for `(2,3) * (1,3) * (1,2)` - perhaps it could be edited to include your helpful example?

Comment: If this was a simple code golf, I would submit this Perl 6 one `{.combinations(.end).map: *.reduce: &prefix:<[*]>}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Python, 3(n-2) operations, score = 2994

```py
l = list(map(float, input().split()))
n = len(l)

left = [0] * len(l)
right = [0] * len(l)
left[0] = l[0]
right[-1] = l[-1]
for i in range(1,len(l)-1):
  left[i] = l[i] * left[i - 1]
  right[-i-1] = l[-i-1] * right[-i]

result = [0] * len(l)
result[-1] = left[-2]
result[0] = right[1]
for i in range(1, len(l) - 1):
  result[i] = left[i - 1] * right[i+1]

print(result)
```

The arrays `left` and `right` contain the cumulated products of the array from the left and from the right, respectively.

### EDIT: Proof that 3(n-2) is the optimal number of operations needed for n >= 2, if we only use multiplication.

We will do that by induction; by the above algorithm, we just have to prove that for n >= 2, 3(n-2) is a lower bound on the number of multiplications needed.

For n = 2, we need at least 0 = 3(2-2) multiplications, so the result is trivial.

Let n > 2, and suppose for n - 1 elements, we need at least 3(n-3) multiplications. Consider a solution for n elements with k multiplications.
Now, we remove the last of these elements as if it was 1, and simplify all multiplications directly by it. We also remove the multiplication leading to the product of all the other elements, since that one is not needed as it can never be used as an intermediate value to get the product of n-2 of the other elements, since division is not allowed. This leaves us with l multiplications, and a solution for n - 1 elements.

By induction hypothesis, we have l >= 3(n-3).

Now, let's have a look at how many multiplications were removed. One of them was the one leading to the product of all elements except the last. Moreover, the last element was used directly in at least two multiplications: if it was used in only one, then it was used when multiplying by an intermediate result consisting in some product of the other elements; let's say, without loss of generality, this this intermediate result included the first element in the product. Then, there is no way to get the product of all the elements but the first, since every product that contains the last element is either the last element, or contains the first element.

We thus have k >= l+3 >= 3(n-2), proving the claimed theorem.

Comment: This turns out [very clean in Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hR8FWoSqzIDyzJENBQ0tTQaM4OTEvB8w0VMiB8ougfBWFksTMHAWg@P/cxMw8oNaCosy8EqB4mkK0kY6xjomOaex/AA): `f l = zipWith (*) (scanl (*) 1 l) (scanr (*) 1 $ tail  l)`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60810/discussion-on-answer-by-nore-fastest-algorithm-to-take-the-product-of-all-subset).

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), score 2994

```hs
group :: Num a => [a] -> [[a]]
group (a:b:t) = [a,b] : group t
group [a] = [[a]]
group [] = []

(%) :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a -> a
a % 1 = a
1 % b = b
a % b = a * b

prod_one_or_two :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> a
prod_one_or_two [a, b] = a % b
prod_one_or_two [x] = x

insert_new_value :: (Num a, Eq a) => ([a], a) -> [a]
insert_new_value ([a, b], c) = [c % b, c % a]
insert_new_value ([x], c) = [c]

products_but_one :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
products_but_one [a] = [1]
products_but_one l = 
    do combination <- combinations ; insert_new_value combination
    where 
        pairs = group l
        subresults = products_but_one $ map prod_one_or_two pairs
        combinations = zip pairs subresults
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHLTsMwELz7K/ZApRQliMItEG5c@YHKitapRaM6dohtWvHzYe1EfeAIH7yP2Z3ZtfdoD1KpcfwcjO@hLOHDd4BQvcEWORRkyHI2wRmWonRrqAjMBYcSpryb8dBS3XRsY4Izlq3WgT2L9Dm8fwGugwoGjeliCCvYUD2yDXmCPBFzwUO4p4j1g9nVRsvaDLU7mkXKeXBMimloEDySEWkKnwJ2YqzVVg6u1vJYf6PyclElI5k8@EVUTJuySS6HJj5YEzQpILNcfbqU8mlR3zhbC@/CkP9tGuST@vkvNguQIoABnZ2BxnSi1ehao@G1uA4tvEAy5hUeGY57OciJLJwe28ES@/T56py3XgzSeuUCmMxzBx328Pc7IteZ4WawCn7afha7UI8qLvzwmMNTDsUzZx22Ogq22pFK@hDjLw)

Say we're given the list `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]`. We first group it into pairs `[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h]]`. Then, we recurse on the half-size list `pairs` of their products to get `subresults`

```hs
[a*b, c*d, e*f, g*h] -> [(c*d)*(e*f)*(g*h), (a*b)*(e*f)*(g*h), (a*b)*(c*d)*(g*h), (a*b)*(c*d)*(e*f)]
```

If we take the first element `(c*d)*(e*f)*(g*h)`, and multiply it by `b` and `a` respectively, we get the product of all but `a` and all but `b`. Doing this for every pair and recursive result with that pair missing, we get out final result. The odd-length case is specially handled by having the odd element passed unpaired to the recursive step, and the product of the remaining elements returned is the product without it.

The number of multiplications `t(n)` is `n/2` for the pairing product, `t(n/2)` for the recursive call, and another `n` for the products with individual elements. This gives `t(n) = 1.5 * n + t(n/2)` for odd `n`. Using a more precise counts for odd `n` and ignoring multiplying with `1` for the base case gives score `2997` for `n=1000`.

Comment: This is very nice.

Comment: I think the reason why the score is 2995 and not 2994 as in my answer is that it computes the product of all numbers as well in the non-power of two case, which is later truncated. Maybe a careful handling in `products_but_one'` could avoid that by returning something of the correct length.

Comment: @nore I found I had an extra multiplication in my count because I forgot the base case has a `1` that is free to multiply. I think the padding 1 didn't affect things, but I cleaned up my algorithm to not use them.

Comment: Does this code assume the input is integers?

Comment: @Lembik It does, but only in the optional type annotations. I'll change them all to `float`.

Comment: Surely you mean `Num a => a`, or at least `Double`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Is this right?

Comment: Looks good, I forgot about the need for `Eq`. Although `group` doesn't need either constraint.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I was surprised `Num` doesn't imply `Eq`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @xnor It used to, but was removed in GHC 7.4 because it rules out (or makes awkward) useful new instances. See [libraries list thread](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-September/016699.html).

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), score 9974

```hs
partition :: [Float] -> ([Float], [Float])
partition = foldr (\a (l1,l2) -> (l2, a:l1)) ([],[])

(%) :: Float -> Float -> Float
a % 1 = a
1 % b = b
a % b = a*b

merge :: (Float, [Float]) -> (Float, [Float]) -> (Float, [Float])
merge (p1,r1) (p2, r2) = (p1%p2, map(%p1)r2 ++ map(%p2)r1)

missing_products' :: [Float] -> (Float, [Float])
missing_products' [a] = (a,[1])
missing_products' l = merge res1 res2
    where
        (l1, l2) = partition l
        res1 = missing_products' l1
        res2 = missing_products' l2

missing_products :: [Float] -> [Float]
missing_products = snd . missing_products'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLBTsQgEL3zFXOwEVxshGOTevQnamOmLu6SZVsCNX5@HbBaXfYgB/IY3nvzhvaI8WScWxaPYbaznUZoGuie3IRzD/ePwFcsv4uCbdQW3ia3D8CfEbhT0mmRNU5LwMYpIUjfy45EjFciWWeTRPoLGEIFigyRKUIDoSHXEsK7gbGzCQeTHHgWbHlyx3/UVgfulQyKgnkKGShwm0pVOp3R88orETTsdutJCyJTdxujHQ8vPkz799c53l4@U9GsEHTYp14oO3X13tHtV8RgokqbZkDr42iCySit9MzgcuztO7if6ywln9Jd/ebo6xxdDnox5wpLWgtx3ENdui5prk7VtXogGdr01/hgxxluCjK45RM)

A divide-and-conquer strategy, very reminiscent of merge sort. Doesn't do any indexing.

The function `partition` splits the list into as-equal-as-possible halves by putting alternating elements on opposite sides of the partition. We recursively merge the results `(p,r)` for each of the halves, with `r` the list of products-with-one-missing, and `p` the overall product.

For the output for the full list, the missing element must be in one of the halves. The product with that element missing is a one-missing-product for the half it's in, multiplied by the full product for the other half. So, we multiply each product-with-one-missing by the full product of the other half and make a list of the results, as `map(*p1)r2 ++ map(*p2)r1)`. This takes `n` multiplications, where `n` is the length. We also need to make a new full-product `p1*p2` for future use, costing 1 more multiplication.

This gives the general recursion for for the number of operations `t(n)` with `n` even: `t(n) = n + 1 + 2 * t(n/2)`. The odd one is similar, but one of the sublists is `1` larger. Doing out the recursion, we get `n*(log_2(n) + 1)` multiplications, though the odd/even distinction affects that exact value. The values up to `t(3)` are improved by not multiplying by `1` by defining a variant `(%)` of `(*)` that shortcuts the `_*1` or `1*_` cases.

This gives `9975` multiplications  for `n=1000`. I believe Haskell's laziness means the unused overall product in the outer layer is not computed for `9974`; if I'm mistaken, I could omit it explicitly.

Comment: You beat me by the timestamp one minute earlier.

Comment: If it's hard to work out the formula  exactly, feel free to just run it for `n = 1000` and count the arithmetic operations in  the code.

Comment: Since our code is basically the same, I don't understand how you got to `9974` and not `9975` multiplications for `n = 1000` (in the case of computing the overall product in the outer layer). Did you include a `1` in the input you used to test it?

Comment: @nore You're right, I was off by one. I wrote code to do the recursion for the number of multiplication function calls. Counting calls directly would be more reliable -- does anyone know how I'd do that in Haskell?

Comment: @xnor From my very limited Haskell experience, I know no easy way to do that except by using [unsafePerformIO](https://wiki.haskell.org/UnsafePerformIO). Maybe someone has a better idea for that than me, however.

Comment: @xnor you can use `trace` from `Debug.Trace` with a catch-all `| trace "call!" False = undefined` guard, I think. But this uses `unsafePerformIO` under the hood, so it's not really that much of an improvement.

Answer (score 4):

### O(n log n) operations, score = 9974

Works with a binary tree.

### Python

```py
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
n = len(l)

p = [0] * n + l
for i in range(n - 1, 1, -1):
  p[i] = p[i + i] * p[i + i+1]

def mul(x, y):
  if y == None:
    return x
  return x * y

r = [None] * n + [[None]] * n
for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
  r[i] = [mul(p[i + i + 1], x) for x in r[i + i]] + [mul(p[i + i], x) for x in r[i + i + 1]]

u = r[1]
j = 1
while j <= n:
  j += j
print(u[n+n-j:] + u[:n+n-j])
```

This also requires list addition operations, and some arithmetic on numbers that are not the input values; not sure if that counts. The `mul` function is there to save n operations for the base case, to avoid wasting them by multiplying by 1.
In any case, this is O(n log n) operations. The exact formula is, if only counting arithmetic operations on input numbers, with `j = floor(log_2(n))`:
`j * (2^(j + 1) - n) + (j + 1) * (2 * n - 2^(j + 1)) - 2`.

Thanks to @xnor for saving one operation with the idea of not computing the outer product!

The last part is to output the products in order of the missing term.

Comment: If it's hard to work out the formula  exactly, feel free to just run it for `n = 1000` and count the arithmetic operations in  the code.

Comment: I counted 10975 operations...?

Comment: `p[i] = p[i + i] * p[i + i+1]` isn't counted

Comment: This is about `n log2 n + n` operations (which is O(nlogn) btw

Comment: @HyperNeutrino the operations in `p[i] = p[i + i] * p[i + i + 1]` should be saved by the multiplication optimization. I might have counted one too many, however.

Comment: Can't you assign a variable to `i + i` in the second for loop so you save on operations?

Comment: @ZacharyT I could, but I didn't include the operations on indices (to oppose to input numbers) in the count. I could do that of course, but I don't think this is the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: Did you count the `n-1` in the `range` calls?

Comment: @ZacharyT same, I didn't count this operation as it is only an operation on indices; I am going to wait for an explicit answer on this point.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), score 2994

```hs
group :: [a] -> Either [(a, a)] (a, [(a, a)])
group [] = Left []
group (a : l) = case group l of
  Left pairs -> Right (a, pairs)
  Right (b, pairs) -> Left ((a, b) : pairs)

products_but_one :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
products_but_one [_] = [1]
products_but_one [a, b] = [b, a]
products_but_one l = case group l of
  Left pairs ->
    let subresults =
          products_but_one [a * b | (a, b) <- pairs]
    in do ((a, b), c) <- zip pairs subresults; [c * b, c * a]
  Right (extra, pairs) ->
    let subresult : subresults =
          products_but_one (extra : [a * b | (a, b) <- pairs])
    in subresult : do ((a, b), c) <- zip pairs subresults; [c * b, c * a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVHLTsMwELznK@bAIUZtRa@B9MYNceBqWZGTuo2Fm0R@SAjx78GPRK2UIBC@rD07Ozu7brl5F0qN41n3bkBRgHKG7QHP0rZCg@Z8A04YQpwfJEtsylDiRZysv01QzlFAEY833AgkUKE/ZUjMgUttQoM3eW5tlI0Q8YQJqmco0GJRHmg18dITNxt0f3SNNVXtbNV3Ijh/dRdwlId5BB@WPFoF03S/lgpNYtY7WKtVv4/l34ASFsbVWhinrEEZwXRWmuIeNb4wjfi0TVosFskOx34ef4Mm5j/lMPW7NnkEbYKQ5/jA2XWb4sNqfrPRpUO/1r@6TWoofrZNZt@38v@bYVTxp3a7/QPLLtxrlt6R7Czuls7U@A0)

#### How it works

This is a cleaned up version of [xnor’s algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127156/39242) that deals with the odd case in a more straightforward way (edit: it looks like xnor has cleaned it up the same way):

[a, b, c, d, e, f, g] ↦
[a, bc, de, fg] ↦
[(bc)(de)(fg), a(de)(fg), a(bc)(fg), a(bc)(de)] by recursion ↦
[(bc)(de)(fg), a(de)(fg)c, a(de)(fg)b, a(bc)(fg)e, a(bc)(fg)d, a(bc)(de)g, a(bc)(de)f]

[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] ↦
[ab, cd, ef, gh] ↦
[(cd)(ef)(gh), (ab)(ef)(gh), (ab)(cd)(gh), (ab)(cd)(ef)] by recursion ↦
[(cd)(ef)(gh)b, (cd)(ef)(gh)a, (ab)(ef)(gh)d, (ab)(ef)(gh)c, (ab)(cd)(gh)f, (ab)(cd)(gh)e, (ab)(cd)(ef)h, (ab)(cd)(ef)g].

Comment: "Given n numbers in an array (you can't assume they are integers), " We can't assume they are integers

Answer (score 2):

## O((n-2)*n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>): Trivial Solution

This is just the trivial solution that multiplies together each of the subsets:

## Python

```
def product(array): # Requires len(array) - 1 multiplication operations
    if not array: return 1
    result = array[0]
    for value in array[1:]:
        result *= value
    return result

def getSubsetProducts(array):
    products = []
    for index in range(len(array)): # calls product len(array) times, each time calling on an array of size len(array) - 1, which means len(array) - 2 multiplication operations called len(array) times
        products.append(product(array[:index] + array[index + 1:]))
    return products
```

Note that this also requires `n` list-addition operations; not sure if that counts. If that is not allowed, then `product(array[:index] + array[index + 1:])` can be replaced to `product(array[:index]) * product(array[index + 1:])`, which changes the formula to `O((n-1)*n)`.

Comment: You can  add your own score to the answer.  998*1000 in this case.

Comment: Doesn't need your `product` function `O(n)` operations? one for each element in the array (althought this can easily be changed to `O(n-1)`)

Comment: @RomanGräf True. I'll change it to O(n-1) but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This has been changed to [tag:atomic-code-golf]...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer What does that make my score now? Unless I am being blatantly stupid, don't the tag and the specs contradict each other now?

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 7540

A tripartite merge strategy. I think I can do even better than this, with a yet large merge. It's O(n log n).

EDIT: Fixed a miscount.

```
count = 0
def prod(a, b):
    if a == 1: return b
    if b == 1: return a
    global count
    count += 1
    return a * b

def tri_merge(subs1, subs2, subs3):
    total1, missing1 = subs1
    total2, missing2 = subs2
    total3, missing3 = subs3

    prod12 = prod(total1, total2)
    prod13 = prod(total1, total3)
    prod23 = prod(total2, total3)

    new_missing1 = [prod(m1, prod23) for m1 in missing1]
    new_missing2 = [prod(m2, prod13) for m2 in missing2]
    new_missing3 = [prod(m3, prod12) for m3 in missing3]

    return prod(prod12, total3), new_missing1 + new_missing2 + new_missing3

def tri_partition(nums):
    split_size = len(nums) // 3
    a = nums[:split_size]
    second_split_length = split_size + (len(nums) % 3 == 2)
    b = nums[split_size:split_size + second_split_length]
    c = nums[split_size + second_split_length:]
    return a, b, c

def missing_products(nums):
    if len(nums) == 1: return nums[0], [1]
    if len(nums) == 0: return 1, []
    subs = [missing_products(part) for part in tri_partition(nums)]
    return tri_merge(*subs)

def verify(nums, res):
    actual_product = 1
    for num in nums:
        actual_product *= num
    actual_missing = [actual_product // num for num in nums]
    return actual_missing == res[1] and actual_product == res[0]

nums = range(2, int(input()) + 2)
res = missing_products(nums)

print("Verified?", verify(nums, res))
if max(res[1]) <= 10**10: print(res[1])

print(len(nums), count)
```

The relevant function is `missing_products`, which gives the overall product and all of the ones with a missing element.

Comment: did you count the multiplications in `tri_merge`? Also you can replace the `2 * split_size + ...` in `tri_partition` with `split_size + split_size + ...`.

Comment: @RomanGräf I restructured it as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

## C++, score: 5990, O([2NlogN]/3)

This implementation uses a binary tree look up table.  My first implementation was O(NlogN), but a last minute optimization, which looks up the product of all array elements minus a pair, + 2 multiplications saved the day. I think this could still be optimized a bit further, maybe another 16%...

I've left some debugging traces in, only because it's easier to delete them than to rewrite them :)

[Edit] the actual complexity is measured at O([2NlogN]/3) for 100.  It is actually a bit worse than O(NlogN) for small sets, but tends towards O([NlogN]/2) as the array grows very large O(0.57.NlogN) for a a set of 1 million elements.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>

using DataType = long double;

using DataVector = std::vector<DataType>;

struct ProductTree
{
    std::vector<DataVector> tree_;
    size_t ops_{ 0 };

    ProductTree(const DataVector& v) : ProductTree(v.begin(), v.end()) {}
    ProductTree(DataVector::const_iterator first, DataVector::const_iterator last)
    {
        Build(first, last);
    }

    void Build(DataVector::const_iterator first, DataVector::const_iterator last)
    {
        tree_.emplace_back(DataVector(first, last));

        auto size = std::distance(first, last);
        for (auto n = size; n >= 2; n >>= 1)
        {
            first = tree_.back().begin();
            last = tree_.back().end();

            DataVector v;
            v.reserve(n);
            while (first != last) // steps in pairs
            {
                auto x = *(first++);
                if (first != last)
                {
                    ++ops_;
                    x *= *(first++); // could optimize this out,small gain
                }
                v.push_back(x);
            }
            tree_.emplace_back(v);
        }
    }

    // O(NlogN) implementation... 
    DataVector Prod()
    {
        DataVector result(tree_[0].size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tree_[0].size(); ++i)
        {
            auto depth = tree_.size() - 1;
            auto k = i >> depth;
            result[i] = ProductAtDepth(i, depth);
        }
        return result;
    }

    DataType ProductAtDepth(size_t index, size_t depth) 
    {
        if (depth == 0)
        {
            return ((index ^ 1) < tree_[depth].size())
                ? tree_[depth][index ^ 1]
                : 1;
        }
        auto k = (index >> depth) ^ 1;
        
        if ((k < tree_[depth].size()))
        {
            ++ops_;
            return tree_[depth][k] * ProductAtDepth(index, depth - 1);
        }
        return ProductAtDepth(index, depth - 1);
    }    

    // O([3NlogN]/2) implementation... 
    DataVector Prod2()
    {
        DataVector result(tree_[0].size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tree_[0].size(); ++i)    // steps in pairs
        {
            auto depth = tree_.size() - 1;
            auto k = i >> depth;
            auto x = ProductAtDepth2(i, depth);
            if (i + 1 < tree_[0].size())
            {
                ops_ += 2;
                result[i + 1] = tree_[0][i] * x;
                result[i] = tree_[0][i + 1] * x;
                ++i;
            }
            else
            {
                result[i] = x;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    DataType ProductAtDepth2(size_t index, size_t depth)
    {
        if (depth == 1)
        {
            index = (index >> 1) ^ 1;
            return (index < tree_[depth].size())
                ? tree_[depth][index]
                : 1;
        }
        auto k = (index >> depth) ^ 1;

        if ((k < tree_[depth].size()))
        {
            ++ops_;
            return tree_[depth][k] * ProductAtDepth2(index, depth - 1);
        }
        return ProductAtDepth2(index, depth - 1);
    }

};


int main()
{
    //srand(time());

    DataVector data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        auto x = rand() & 0x3;          // avoiding overflow and zero vaolues for testing
        data.push_back((x) ? x : 1);
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    //{
    //  data.push_back(i + 1);
    //}

    //std::cout << "data:[";
    //for (auto val : data)
    //{
    //  std::cout << val << ",";
    //}
    //std::cout << "]\n";

    ProductTree pt(data);
    DataVector result = pt.Prod2();

    //std::cout << "result:[";
    //for (auto val : result)
    //{
    //  std::cout << val << ",";
    //}
    //std::cout << "]\n";
    std::cout << "N = " << data.size() << " Operations :" << pt.ops_ << '\n';

    pt.ops_ = 0;
    result = pt.Prod();

    //std::cout << "result:[";
    //for (auto val : result)
    //{
    //  std::cout << val << ",";
    //}
    //std::cout << "]\n";

    std::cout << "N = " << data.size() << " Operations :" << pt.ops_ << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I'm adding @nore's algorithm, for completeness.  It's really nice, and is the fastest.

```
class ProductFlat
{
private:
    size_t ops_{ 0 };

    void InitTables(const DataVector& v, DataVector& left, DataVector& right)
    {
        if (v.size() < 2)
        {
            return;
        }

        left.resize(v.size() - 1);
        right.resize(v.size() - 1);

        auto l = left.begin();
        auto r = right.rbegin();
        auto ol = v.begin();
        auto or = v.rbegin();

        *l = *ol++;
        *r = *or++;
        if (ol == v.end())
        {
            return;
        }

        while (ol + 1 != v.end())
        {
            ops_ += 2;
            *l = *l++ * *ol++;
            *r = *r++ * *or++;
        }
    }

public:
    DataVector Prod(const DataVector& v)
    {
        if (v.size() < 2)
        {
            return v;
        }

        DataVector result, left, right;
        InitTables(v, left, right);

        auto l = left.begin();
        auto r = right.begin();
        result.push_back(*r++);
        while (r != right.end())
        {
            ++ops_;
            result.push_back(*l++ * *r++);
        }
        result.push_back(*l++);
        return result;
    }

    auto Ops() const
    {
        return ops_;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## dc, score 2994

```dc
#!/usr/bin/dc -f

# How it works:
# The required products are
#
#   (b × c × d × e × ... × x × y × z)
# (a) × (c × d × e × ... × x × y × z)
# (a × b) × (d × e × ... × x × y × z)
# ...
# (a × b × c × d × e × ... × x) × (z)
# (a × b × c × d × e × ... × x × y)
#
# We calculate each parenthesised term by
# multiplying the one above (on the left) or below
# (on the right), for 2(n-2) calculations, followed
# by the n-2 non-parenthesised multiplications
# giving a total of 3(n-2) operations.

# Read input from stdin
?

# We will store input values into stack 'a' and
# accumulated product into stack 'b'.  Initialise
# stack b with the last value read.
sb

# Turnaround function at limit of recursion: print
# accumulated 'b' value (containing b..z above).
[Lbn[ ]nq]sG

# Recursive function - on the way in, we stack up
# 'a' values and multiply up the 'b' values.  On
# the way out, we multiply up the 'a' values and
# multiply each by the corresponding 'b' value.
[dSalb*Sb
z1=G
lFx
dLb*n[ ]n
La*]dsFx

# Do the last a*b multiplication
dLb*n[ ]n

# And we have one final 'a' value that doesn't have a
# corresponding 'b':
La*n
```

I'm assuming that the integer comparison `z1=` (which terminates the recursion when we reach the last value) is free.  This is equivalent to the likes of `foreach` in other languages.

### Demonstrations

```
for i in '2 3 5' '2 3 5 7' '0 2 3 5' '0 0 1 2 3 4'
do printf '%s => ' "$i"; ./127147.dc <<<"$i"; echo
done
2 3 5 => 15 10 6
2 3 5 7 => 105 70 42 30
0 2 3 5 => 30 0 0 0
0 0 1 2 3 4 => 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

A demo with large and small inputs:

```
./127147.dc <<<'.0000000000000000000542101086242752217003726400434970855712890625 1 18446744073709551616'
18446744073709551616 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 .0000000000000000000542101086242752217003726400434970855712890625
```