# Is the question undeleted?

Tags: code-golf, stack-exchange-api

## Challenge

Given a positive integer, determine whether that number is currently being used to represent a question on PPCG.

The question must not have been removed, but may be open or closed.

The number is the one being used in the URL of the question, such as:

> [https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/[input]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/%5Binput%5D)

Note that this questions is tagged [stack-exchange-api](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api), but you may not need this to complete the challenge.

## Examples

> 1: Truthy (represents [Just Another Perl Hacker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1/just-another-perl-hacker))
>
> 3: Falsey (was once [Solve the Tower of Hanoi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3/solve-the-tower-of-hanoi), but was removed by a moderator.
>
> 127030: Falsey (was once [Helping Danny to Maximize his Score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127030/helping-danny-to-maximize-his-score), but was removed by the author.)
>
> 127147: Truthy ([Fastest algorithm to take the product of all subsets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127147/fastest-algorithm-to-take-the-product-of-all-subsets))

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: Just Another Perl Hacker is closed.

Comment: @ATaco It is closed, but the criteria state that `The question must not have been removed, but may be open or closed.` This is to benefit answers that don't use the Stack Exchange API because, I *believe*, a page will give 404 Not Found iff it is not a question or was removed

Comment: @totallyhuman Yes, standard I/O apply

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12962/69054) for those who can see deleted posts

Comment: Uhm, why is the title "Is it an open question?" if the question may be open or closed?

Answer (score 3):

### bash, 52 bytes

```sh
curl -IL codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/$1|grep 2\ 200
```

Takes input as a command line argument, and outputs in the form of exit code: `0` or "success" (truthy) for an undeleted question, and `1` or "failure" (falsy) for a nonexistent or deleted question.

It also prints a bunch of junk to STDERR and potentially STDOUT, but this is [allowed to be ignored](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9658/38080) as per meta.

As an explanation, the `-I` flag to `curl` sends an HTTP HEAD request (fetch only the headers), and `-L` will follow redirects (http to https, and then /q to /questions). The full output from the `curl` command will look something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently                             
Location: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/127030
X-Request-Guid: 1a0b6059-057c-448c-bfc9-a96f1b373abf
Content-Length: 160
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 20 Jun 2017 04:07:30 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 503
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-itm7423-ITM
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1
X-Timer: S1497931651.709631,VS0,VE0
Vary: Fastly-SSL
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Set-Cookie: prov=933ae4b0-81b0-2b37-e26e-59a0fbb6991a; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

HTTP/2 302 
date: Tue, 20 Jun 2017 04:07:31 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
location: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127030/helping-danny-to-maximize-his-score
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-guid: fdcaf556-7ae6-4240-89a1-ace7625f8821
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000
accept-ranges: bytes
via: 1.1 varnish
age: 0
x-served-by: cache-nrt6132-NRT
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-timer: S1497931651.085546,VS0,VE166
vary: Fastly-SSL
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
set-cookie: prov=5e314a4f-0c50-08ef-afa2-9388b37e3b7a; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
cache-control: private
content-length: 204

HTTP/2 404 
date: Tue, 20 Jun 2017 04:07:31 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-guid: 3f72afb7-81e8-4e69-a8ad-474534f2abe6
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000
accept-ranges: bytes
via: 1.1 varnish
age: 0
x-served-by: cache-nrt6132-NRT
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-timer: S1497931651.323339,VS0,VE189
vary: Fastly-SSL
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
set-cookie: prov=cede4119-eba5-d799-e376-848e4e457f07; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
cache-control: private
content-length: 42158
```

Note that the `2\ 200` (equivalent to `'2 200'`) will match the line `HTTP/2 200` if it exists (HTTP OK), and it will not match `HTTP/2 404` (Not Found) for questions that do not exist. (The inclusion of the `2` is necessary to avoid false positives if some of the other headers happen to contain the sequence `200`.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), 112 bytes

Takes input as a string or integer and outputs 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy.

```python
lambda n:len(get('http://api.stackexchange.com/posts/%s?site=codegolf'%n).json()['items'])
from requests import*
```

Comment: Won't this return truthy if the integer provided is the ID of an answer?

Comment: @Shaggy All of these answers do. This is an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 + Requests, <s>107</s> <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>92</s> 79 bytes

```
lambda m:get("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/"+m).ok
from requests import*
```

<sub>-8 bytes by changing `question` to `q`

-1 byte by changing `!=` to `<`, since `200 OK` is less than `404 NOT FOUND`.

-1 byte by changing `https` to `http`

-6 bytes by changing to a `lambda`

-13 bytes using the `ok` attribute</sub>

Comment: You should add `+ Requests` in the header as it's not in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 70 bytes

Takes input as a string and outputs 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy.

```
Check[Import["https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/"<>#];1,0]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>104</s> 102 bytes

Returns a Promise containing a JSON object for truthy or `undefined` for falsey.

```js
n=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/questions/${n}?site=codegolf`).then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.items[0])
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
n=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/questions/${n}?site=codegolf`).then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.items[0])
oninput=_=>f(+i.value).then(console.log);f(i.value=1).then(console.log)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stratos](https://github.com/okx-code/Stratos), 16 bytes

```
f"¹⁵s/%²"r"⁷s"
l
```

Explanation (decompressed:

```
f"api.stackexchange.com/questions/%?site=codegolf"         Replace % with the input, and get from this URL
                                                  r"items" Get the JSON array named "items"
l                                                          Length
```

Prints 1 for truthy, and 0 for falsy.

[Try it!](http://okx.sh/stratos/?code=f%22%C2%B9%E2%81%B5s%2F%25%C2%B2%22r%22%E2%81%B7s%22%0Al&input=3)